# Db2 JDBC Driver EncyptionMethod or AuthenticationMethod

Tags: coldfusion, db2, ibm-cloud

I am trying to connect Db2 database with ColdFusion. I am using IBM Db2 on Cloud and am getting the below error:

> Connection verification failed for data source: "DatabaseName"
>   java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [Macromedia][DB2 JDBC
>   Driver]The encryptionMethod or authenticationMethod specified is not
>   supported by the DB2 server you are connecting to.  The root cause was
>   that: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [Macromedia][DB2
>   JDBC Driver]The encryptionMethod or authenticationMethod specified is
>   not supported by the DB2 server you are connecting to

Comment: What is the connection string, including the options? Are you using the string as shown in the Db2 on Cloud connection information (in the dashboard)?

Comment: also check if you have the write jdbc driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, it may be caused when not adding AuthenticationMethod property.
Here are some related information about it.

**Connecting to Db2 Warehouse using DataDirect driver**
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_1.7.2/com.ibm.nz.hdp.doc/t_hdp_datadirect.html

```
<connectionURL>jdbc:ibm:db2://<your_hostname>:<port>;databaseName=bludb;AuthenticationMethod=encryptedPassword</connectionURL>
```

**C&DS encryptionMethod or authentication specified not supported** 
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/cds-encryptionmethod-or-authentication-specified-not-supported

```
Other AuthenticationMethods are:
AuthenticationMethod=clearText (the default),
AuthenticationMethod= encryptedPassword,
AuthenticationMethod=encryptedPasswordAES,
AuthenticationMethod=encryptedUIDPassword,
AuthenticationMethod= encrytpedUIDPasswordAES,
```

Hope this helps.